# Creat a new ArcSDE connection in Autocad 2014 with using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to creat a software in Visual Studio with VB.NET that connect to Autocad 2014 and add a new connection (ArcSDE Connection) in Autocad , but I don't know how!! 
I need it to get the code that communicates with AutoCAD and create a new ArcSDE connection by using these parameters (Server Name, Instance Name, User Name & Password)

can you help me??

Comment: [ArcSDE SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/welcome.htm)